# "unelected peers to filibuster"

Tags: meaning

I am currently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/u-k-boris-johnson-fails-204758019.html), a paragraph says,

> The bill was then sent to the House of Lords and will return to the Commons by Friday evening, the Press Association reported, ***after an earlier plan to get unelected peers to filibuster was dropped.***

Could someone help me understand what this bold and italic line is trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UK a Bill is first voted on by the House of Commons. If passed, it then goes to the Upper House (the House of Lords) to be voted on there. If accepted, the Bill then returns to the House of Commons for further debate etc.

The phrase "unelected peers" means the members of the House of Lords. The "unelected" adjective is irrelevant to the meaning of the whole sentence. It is a "dig" that the members of the Upper House (of Lords) are not elected, unlike the members of the Lower House (of Commons).

To [**filibuster**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/filibuster) means to employ delaying tactics to prevent the Bill being passed. There was a plan to do this in the Upper House, but it was dropped.

Therefore the Bill is expected to return to the Commons after a voting decision in the Upper House.

The bolded part of the sentence could be written like this:

> after an earlier plan (to get <strike>unelected</strike> peers to filibuster) was dropped.

Comment: Once upon a time the 'unelected peers' were mostly people who had inherited their titles and their seats in the Lords; they were aristocrats. Nowadays, almost all the hereditary peers have been expelled from the Lords so its membership is largely Life Peers, who got there by being put forward by the leaders of the major political parties. Unelected, yes, but politically unconnected, no.

Comment: @JeremyC that's right, but my point was not political, it was to show that the sentence isn't talking about one section of the Lords, but the Lords in general. However the purpose of the sentence's author probably was political in including it: "how undemocratic is that!"